# ValueError at /adm/appt/ Expected table or queryset, not str

Tags: django, django-tables2

Getting the following error when trying to use django_tables2

```
ValueError at /adm/appt/
Expected table or queryset, not str
```

I have run all the updates and upgrades on the packages
    Error

```
 Request Method:    GET
    Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/adm/appt/
    Django Version: 2.0.3
    Exception Type: ValueError
    Exception Value:    
    Expected table or queryset, not str
    Exception Location: C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django_tables2\templatetags\django_tables2.py in render, line 147
    Python Executable:  C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe
    Python Version: 3.6.3
```

View: Think i'm initializing the table properly as well as sending the queryset

```
def ApptView(request):
    table = AppointmentTable(Appointment.objects.all())
    model = Appointment
    table_class = AppointmentTable
    filterset_class = AppointmentFilter
    RequestConfig(request).configure(table)
    return render(request,'adm/index2.html', {'table': table})
```

HTML

```
{% load render_table from django_tables2 %}


<body>


          {% render_table AppointmentTable %}


</div>


</body>
```

Tables

```
import django_tables2 as tables
from .models import Appointment

class AppointmentTable(tables.Table):
    class Meta:
        model = Appointment
        template_name = 'django_tables2/bootstrap.html'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are calling the template tag is wrong - there is no `AppointmentTable` in your view context, hence the error. Change it as follows:

```
{% render_table table %}
```

Where `table` is the context variable that you've supplied to the `render()` method in your view.